# Multiple static library inclusion in CMake TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES

Tags: c++, cmake, dynamic-linking

I have a `CMake` multiple definition linking problem with an executable that depends on a shared library that contains a static library.

I create a shared library `foo` that depends on a static library `bar`.

```
add_library(foo SHARED foo.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo bar)
```

By definition, the content of `bar` is in library `foo`.

Then I create an executable `exe` that depends on `foo`.

```
add_executable(exe exe.cpp)
target_link_libraries(exe foo)
```

At linking time, I have a `multiple definition` warning/error that tells me that functions in library `bar` are present twice. When looking at the linking command, I see that `exe` is linked against `bar` and `foo`, which is not consistent.

Do I miss something in the declaration of dependencies? Do I miss a magic `CMake` keyword?

Comment: You need a http://sscce.org/

Comment: the problem he highlights is a common one. Any cmake bittervet would have known what he meant :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
add_library(foo SHARED <foo source files>)
target_link_libraries(foo PRIVATE bar)
```

If other libraries are linked against `foo`, make sure to use `CMake` [keyword](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html)`PRIVATE`,`PUBLIC` or `INTERFACE`